# Copying GoPro metadata with ffmpeg - Could not find tag for codec none

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to use ffmpeg to copy the metadata of a gopro file.
The most basic demonstration of the problem would be to copy everything to a new file:

```
ffmpeg -y -i source.MP4 -c copy -copy_unknown -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map_metadata 0 result.MP4
```

This produces the error:

```
Could not find tag for codec none in stream #2, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:4 --
```

As I understand it this means that ffmpeg doesn't apply the -c copy operation correctly and instead complains that there is no encoder for the data streams. The same error happens for 0:2 and 0:4

While searching on google if have found some people who have had the same issue in the past but I have also found some reports of it working.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong or is this actually a bug?

Here is the ffprobe and the link to the [GoPro file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/pgtkwl3eajvpuqk/source.MP4/file).

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'source.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2021-05-17T22:36:48.000000Z
    firmware        : HD7.01.01.90.00
  Duration: 00:00:02.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 58664 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 2704x1520 [SAR 1:1 DAR 169:95], 58557 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-05-17T22:36:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
      timecode        : 02:43:36:15
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 187 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-05-17T22:36:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro AAC
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      timecode        : 02:43:36:15
  Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-05-17T22:36:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 02:43:36:15
  Stream #0:3(eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 30 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-05-17T22:36:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET
  Stream #0:4(eng): Data: none (fdsc / 0x63736466), 16 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-05-17T22:36:48.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro SOS
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
Unsupported codec with id 100359 for input stream 3
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 4
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not really. I am now parsing the raw video file and looking for the metadata tags. Its not a nice solution and it could be a lot better if I took the time to learn about mp4 but it works well enough. Its not 100% perfect yet (some issue with invalid values) but you can take a look at [my Github](https://github.com/tommaier123/GyroSmooth)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the container but i don't know if this will be acceptable to you

```
ffmpeg -y -i source.MP4 -c copy -copy_unknown -map 0:v -map 0:a -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map_metadata 0 result.mov
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately thats not an option. I am trying to extreact the gopro 7 gyro metadata, smooth it and recreate the file. Usually the data from the hero 7 is too noisy to be stabilized with reelsteady but I hope filtering it will make it useable.
Reelsteady only takes MP4 though.